# Find if AD group login is in use or not

Tags: sql-server, logins

Is there a way to find out if AD group login is in use or not? Basically I am trying to find out which logins are used and decommission ones not in use. Note that it isn't possible to decomm them by disabling them first as it would cause issues if they are actually in use. Does sp_whoisactive or sp_who2 active show anything if it is coming from AD group? I tried to check it on my server but unfortunately didn't get anything concrete. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed, the way I've managed this in the past (hunting for people using an SA login when they shouldn't, but same process) is to setup a SQL Agent job and dump sp_who2 into a table every 5-10 mins for a period of a month (adjust to you work cycles a day/week may do.).

[Pinal Dave post putting sp_who2 into a temp table](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/12/17/sql-server-inserting-sp_who2-into-a-table/)

Once its in a temp table from example, you can filter to remove irrelevant logins, maybe filter login by your domain if that's all you care about then insert into a static table with the same schema somewhere.

Then run query at the end of the period, group by login, add counts if you wish. To find out if they're within a particular AD group I'd then pass this list into a PowerShell script to lookup group memberships, if you have the access.

If you have large amounts of activity and care about disk space, maybe add a housekeeping section to the Job to remove duplicates each run.

Alternately if you have logging of failed and successful logins turned on at instance level you could retrospectively just query the SQL Server logs for logins if they go back far enough. To get this into a list you can pass into PowerShell you'd need to do a little text manipulation to just get the logins but its not too hard, paste into excel > substring or replace, save as csv for PS to use.
[MSSQLTIPS how to read error log with T-SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/how-to-read-log-file-in-sql-server-using-tsql/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a logon trigger

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS  

IF SUSER_NAME() = 'DOMAIN\YourGroupName'
BEGIN
    -- do something here to log the group has been used
END;
```